# Renaming Column Header with date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract the date from the columns which have dates in it and keep them as a column header of those specific columns from which they were extracted. Also, all the previous column headers will be the first row. The Column headers where dates are present I wanted to extract those specific dates and keep them as column headers from the index where they were extracted from along with the previous column headers .So the new column headers are Company, Sector, the date
[image]

Comment: kindly explain your question a little bit more

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the code.

Comment: I wanted to extract the date from the columns which have dates in it and keep them as a column header of those specific columns from which they were extracted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can do in this way:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

for col in df.columns:
    try:
        match = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', col)
        date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    except AttributeError:
        continue
    df.rename(columns={col:date}, inplace=True)
```

### Edit after the comment:

Input:

```
  company  dsp mid cap 2019-07-31_y  fds  dsp p 2019-07-30
0       a                         3    8                 5
1       b                         4    9                 6
```

.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
df.loc[len(df)] = 0
df = df.shift()
df.iloc[0] = df.columns
for col in df.columns:
    try:
        match = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', col)
        date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    except AttributeError:
        continue
    df.rename(columns={col:date}, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
   company                2019-07-31  fds        2019-07-30
0  company  dsp mid cap 2019-07-31_y  fds  dsp p 2019-07-30
1        a                         3    8                 5
2        b                         4    9                 6
```

Comment: Yes this is right in a way  but the column headers will be just the dates and the all the previous column headers will be shifted 1 row below

Comment: @Mihir I modified the answer, please check if it is what you mean